# coming from java to nodejs whats the convention for error handling logging? e.message or e.stack?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I come from java, when I got an expected error I printed stack traces.  I'm coming now to work on nodejs (never really worked on javascript).  and in the nodejs project which I need to maintain (project was already coded by other javascript developers) I see error logging following:

`logger.error('some message ' + e.message)`

or

`logger.error('some message ' + e);`

or

`logger.error('some message ' + e.toString());`

or

`logger.error('some message');`

I saw no stacktraces in logs.
Coming from java I converted a few errors to:

`logger.error('some message ' + e.stack)`

but then when a peer javascript developer reviewed that he had a bad eye on me and asked me why do I do that? I told him if the error is unexpected we want all the information about it.  He was very upset that I want the stack and not the message, his claim is that it would clutter the logs, so I said but the error is unexpected, he told me this is nodejs here no stacktraces here.  I still want `.stack` but all the javascript developers do not want it they think it's bad practice to print the `.stack`, I feel I lose important information.  We ended up by him changing my `.stack` to `.message`.

I looked at logs and sometimes the `.stack` just prints two lines not much of a stack, however for me the first line where it printed the filename and the line number where the problem happened is justifying the `stack`, the javascript developer claim in this case was `I can search the error message in code and find it`, for me that is not suffice because i don't think this is scalable a day would come where we would find multiple places with the same printing and if we had a stack we would know exactly which file printed the error and in certain cases also have stack.

Coming from java to javascript - am i missing something? should I do `e.message` and not `e.stack`? am i taking something from java that i should not be?

thanks

Comment: Nice edit, but make sure you clean up your spelling and grammatical errors also.

Comment: For the record, we're not really here to solve coworker disputes.  Find a level of detail in the log that everyone can be happy with, and stick to that.